# Stacks, java,stack cannot be resolved type ,

Tags: java, stack

trying to make a stack that lets the users input how many numbers gonna be in stack first in first out , with 2 methods push and pop , push puts element on the stack and pop removes the element on top .Attempting to call the push method and
the stack have more spaces then an exception is thrown. Attempting to call the pop and
stack is empty then even if an exception is thrown. The question is little hard to understand but thats because of my english

Here is my main class (Application)

```
package com.example.undantag.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stack2 st = new Stack2();

          System.out.println("Stack "+st);

          System.out.println("Please enter how many numbers you would like to enter");
          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
          int totalnumber = scan.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Please enter the number you would like to begin");
          int beginnumber = scan.nextInt();
          showPush(st, beginnumber, totalnumber);

          System.out.println("Please enter how many numbers you would like to delete");
          int deletenumber = scan.nextInt();

          if(deletenumber > totalnumber){

          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid number"); 
          }

          else{


          for(int i=0; i<=deletenumber; i++)
          {
           showpop(st);

         }

         }
    }
}
```

This is the second class

```
package com.example.undantag.main;

public class Stack2 {           
        public static int i;

        static int TotalNumber(int totalnumber){

             return totalnumber;
        }

         static void showPush(Stack st, int a, int totalnumber){

            for(int i = 0; i <=totalnumber; i++)
            {
                 st.push(new Integer (a++));
                 System.out.println("Push("+a + ") ");

            }
        }
        static void showpop(Stack st){

            System.out.print("Pop: ");
            Integer a = (Integer) st.pop();
            System.out.println(a);
            System.out.println("Stack: "+st);

         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Stack` instead of `Stack2` here

```
static void showPush(Stack st, int a, int totalnumber){
```

Did you mean to use `Stack2`?

There's a `Stack` class in `java.util.`. You need to `import` it.

```
import java.util.Stack;
```

Note that `Stack` is a generic parametrized class.

Comment: On top of that you're also using `showpush()` and `showpop()` without calling the type as well (e.g. `Stack2.showpush())`.

Comment: thanks for that notis Sotirios it was the import java.util.stack i was missing , Jeroen any idea how i should do in that case?